# Generate ionic sdk

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I want to build a chat application using ionic 4, and also use the same as a component within android and ios native application. Is there any way I can generate an android and ios SDK using ionic project?

Answer (score 0):

Interfacing with a native SDK that was machine-generated from Typescript sounds like a nightmare. Even if it's technically possible, I would never attempt it.

Comment: so is it a bad choice to develop native SDK with hydride frameworks?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Cordova along with ionic to build for Android and iOS. 
https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted

Once you have installed Cordova, build the application in iOS by using CLI:

```
$ ionic cordova prepare ios
```

Android:

```
$ ionic cordova prepare android
```

For further information, you can take a look at these links: 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/ios

https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/android

Comment: I am asking whether I can generate SDK from the ionic project that can be used in other native Android or IoS projects.